# What is the intent for the first activity launched?

Tags: android, android-intent

When you launch for the first time ,does the starting activity receive any intent?
If it does, where does it come from? which class starts it?

Comment: Why you want to use this ? Do you want to check if your application is going to run first time in device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is Looper which is instructed by ActivityManager initiated by eg. App drawer and usually it sends intent with

`action = "android.intent.action.MAIN"`

and

`category = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`

Usually there is no data (extras) attached.

You can write your own Launcher it would require do to the following:

1. get the list of installed packages
2. check if package responds to intent with fields as mentioned above.

   a. If there are multiple classes which resonds to intent you need to handle all of them (add icons)
3. If user clicks on an icon, send intent to that package with proper intent.